How to update list of cipher suites gPRC server can use with OpenSSL?
There is one environment variable gRPC provides for adding cipher suites.
* GRPC_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES
  A colon separated list of cipher suites to use with OpenSSL
  Defaults to:
    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

But after updating this environment variable I am assuming that gRPC server need to be started again to use new value of this environment variable. I want to add new cipher suites at run time that gRPC server can use for new connections.
Is there any way we can add new cipher suites that a gRPC server can use and server doesn't need to be restarted to reflect this change?
I've updated the environment variable and started the server again. Did not find any way to reflect new cipher suites with restarting the gRPC server.
